# Delete option not available in tree view odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

My odoo tree view doesn't seem to have a delete option[image]

as seen in the image, i have only export option! Did i miss something in my view?

```
       <record id="physical_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">physical.tree.view</field>
            <field name="model">arrivals.physical</field>
            <field name= "arch" type = "xml">
                <tree string="Physical">
                    <field name="lotno"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

the ir.model.access.csv has the line

```
access_arrivals_physical,access.arrivals.physical,model_arrivals_physical,base.group_user,1,1,1,0
```

Comment: You probably don't have the access rights to delete.

Comment: @CZoellner i've added the entry for the model in ir.model.access.csv to the question. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no delete/unlink rights on that model. The last column in the csv is for `perm_unlink` field in `ir.model.access` and you've set that to `0`. So globally no one except Superuser/Odoobot has the right to delete records of that model.

Comment: Ok. I was confused as i've logged in as administrator and still was unable to delete. Thanks for the info on superuser.